# Modify xml to merge child nodes to a single node

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have XML coming as response from a service.

```
var Response = httpService.GetResponse();
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(Response);
```

The xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Version="4.0">
  <Parent>
    <ChildType1>contentA</ChildType1>
    <ChildType2>contentB</ChildType2>
    <ChildType3>contentC</ChildType3>
  </Parent>
  <Parent>
    <ChildType1>contentD</ChildType1>
    <ChildType3>contentE</ChildType3>
  </Parent>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

How can I edit this so it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Version="4.0">
  <Parent>
    <ChildType1>contentA</ChildType1>
    <ChildType2>contentB</ChildType2>
    <ChildType3>contentC</ChildType3>
    <ChildType1>contentD</ChildType1>
    <ChildType3>contentE</ChildType3>
  </Parent>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Comment: Where's your code? Kindly show it as well.

Comment: Rather than trying to edit the doc, it may be useful to start a new one and enumerate the ChildType* nodes (or all the child nodes of Parent nodes), copying them into a new doc one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple once you understand how to play with XDocument, XElement.
I've just created a `List<XElement>` to collect all the child elements and then I'll just append them to a new parent and assign the parent to the root.

I would highly recommend creating a new document rather than updating existing one.

**Solution 1:** Verbose version to understand how it works.

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(str);
List<XElement> allChildNodes = new List<XElement>();
foreach (var parent in xDoc.Root.Elements("Parent"))
{
    allChildNodes.AddRange(parent.Descendants());
}
XElement xParent = new XElement("Parent");
xParent.Add(allChildNodes);
xDoc.Root.Descendants().Remove();
xDoc.Root.Add(xParent);
```

**Solution 2:** Thanks to Jeff Mercado, we have a compact version.

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(str);
xDoc.Root.ReplaceNodes(
    new XElement("Parent", // New parent element is created
    xDoc.Root.Elements("Parent").Elements()));
```

**Output:**

```
<root>
  <Parent>
    <ChildType1>contentA</ChildType1>
    <ChildType2>contentB</ChildType2>
    <ChildType3>contentC</ChildType3>
    <ChildType1>contentD</ChildType1>
    <ChildType3>contentE</ChildType3>
  </Parent>
</root>
```

Comment: This Pefectly worked for me. Thank you so much. only change I did was , allChildNodes.AddRange(parent.Descendants());  i used  allChildNodes.AddRange(parent.Elements())

Answer (score 0):

To replace the `Parent` nodes, you could utilize `XElement.ReplaceNodes()` to replace the child nodes of the root. Replace those nodes with a new `Parent` node that contains the children of the replaced nodes.

```
doc.Root.ReplaceNodes(
    new XElement("Parent",
        doc.Root.Elements("Parent").Elements()
    )
);
```